# Apollo client mutation error handling

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm using GraphQL and mongoose on the server.

When a validation error occurs the GraphQL mutation sends a response with status code 200. On the client side the response looks like this:

```js
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [{
    "message": "error for id...",
    "path": "_id"
  }]
}
```

I would like to get access to the validation error using the `catch` functionality of the apollo-client mutation promise. Something like:

```js
      this.props.deleteProduct(this.state.selectedProductId).then(response => {
         // handle successful mutation
      }).catch(response => {
         const errors = response.errors; // does not work
         this.setState({ errorMessages: errors.map(error => error.message) });
      });
```

How can this be done?

Comment: try using `throw` statement by creating `Error` instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This answer (and arguably the whole question) is now outdated, since mutation errors show up in `catch` in more recent versions of Apollo Client.

GraphQL errors from the mutation currently show up in the `errors` field on the response inside `then`. I think there's definitely a claim to be made that they should show up in the `catch` instead, but here's a snippet of a mutation from [GitHunt](https://github.com/apollographql/GitHunt-React/blob/7f124b2b606b4ae503318e35f1516929a9629b20/ui/routes/NewEntryPage.js#L22):

```
// The container
const withData = graphql(SUBMIT_REPOSITORY_MUTATION, {
  props: ({ mutate }) => ({
    submit: repoFullName => mutate({
      variables: { repoFullName },
    }),
  }),
});

// Where it's called
return submit(repoFullName).then((res) => {
  if (!res.errors) {
    browserHistory.push('/feed/new');
  } else {
    this.setState({ errors: res.errors });
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not work. Error is handled on .catch() and not on .then()

Comment: Yeah this comment is posted before an API change in Apollo Client.

Answer (score 6):

The previous answer from @stubailo does not seem to cover all use cases. If I throw an error on my server side code the response code will be different than 200 and the error will be handled using `.catch()` and not using `.then()`.

[Link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1496) to the issue on GitHub.

The best is probably to handle the error on both `.then()` and `.catch()`.

```js
const { deleteProduct } = this.props;
const { selectedProductId } = this.state;

deleteProduct(selectedProductId)
  .then(res => {
      if (!res.errors) {
          // handle success
      } else {
          // handle errors with status code 200
      }
  })
  .catch(e => {
      // GraphQL errors can be extracted here
      if (e.graphQLErrors) {
          // reduce to get message
          _.reduce(
             e.graphQLErrors,
             (res, err) => [...res, error.message],
             []
          );
      }
   })
```

Comment: Wonder why there isn't a more graceful way to extract error messages and error codes out.

Answer (score 2):

Using graphql tag notation, yo have access to errors:

```
<Mutation mutation={UPDATE_TODO} key={id}>
        {(updateTodo, { loading, error }) => (
          <div>
            <p>{type}</p>
            <form
              onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                updateTodo({ variables: { id, type: input.value } });

                input.value = "";
              }}
            >
              <input
                ref={node => {
                  input = node;
                }}
              />
              <button type="submit">Update Todo</button>
            </form>
            {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
            {error && <p>Error :( Please try again</p>}
          </div>
        )}
      </Mutation>
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html