# Why graphQLErrors are always empty in react components?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, express-graphql

I want to show some errors that comes from graphql server to user.

Have some component with callback that use some mutation

```
onSave() => {
    this.props.mutate({
        mutation: CHANGE_ORDER_MUTATION,
        variables: {
            ids,
        },
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.graphQLErrors) <--- e.graphQLErrors is always empty array = []
    })
}
```

While I'm able to see the `graphQLErrors` error with `apollo-link-error` link.

`const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    console.log(graphQLErrors) <--- errors from server
});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migration to `apollo-server` instead of `express-graphql` solve the problem.

Or you can access errors by `e.networkError.result.errors`

Comment: This answer helped me after spending 3 hours googling how to access graphQLErrors object from response. This should be in official Apollo docs.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the 'catch' will catch errors if your server returns an error code, but not if it returns your errors in the response, but with a success code.  In that case, you just need to get your errors out of the response (keeping your catch too in case the server responds with an error code):

```
this.props.mutate({
  mutation: CHANGE_ORDER_MUTATION,
    variables: {
      ids,
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.errors) {
      // do something with the errors
    } else {
      // there wasn't an error
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.graphQLErrors) <--- e.graphQLErrors is always empty array = []
  })
```

Alternatively - if you use the `graphql()` option from react-apollo, you can specify an onError handler:

```
export default graphql(CHANGE_ORDER_MUTATION, {
  options: (props) => ({
    onCompleted: props.onCompleted,
    onError: props.onError
  }),
})(MyComponent);
```

references:

- https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1828
- [Apollo client mutation error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471623/apollo-client-mutation-error-handling)

Comment: server returns status 500. Also I able to access `graphQLErrors ` errors by `error.networkError.result.errors`

Comment: so you've found what you were looking for then?